# Exposing a Node.js library via ambient TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In an attempt to simplify the use of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise) library for those who prefer coding for Node.js in TypeScript, I created a [complete set of ambient declarations](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/tree/master/typescript) needed to fully represent the library, and included it into the distribution in a separate folder.

However, being not a proficient TypeScript developer, I'm stuck in my research for best practices in doing this sort of thing.

I want to know if simply including ambient declarations in a separate folder is sufficient for developers to start using it right away, without running into problems.

I also want to write some sort of a short guideline for how to use those TypeScript declarations, but frankly, I am myself not doing a good job at it, even though the declarations all seem correct.

So my question is then:

**Is there any article or a guideline to explain it to Node.js developers how to do it with the latest version of TypeScript? (best practices for exposing a Node.js library via TypeScript)**

**UPDATE**

One of the very first problems I'm running into, trying to use such ambient declarations directly, from a TypeScript file - the main file refuses to find the two dependent ones, no matter what change I try, it keeps on saying `Cannot file module...`.

**UPDATE**

I've tried countless per-mutations for how to re-declare the library, and yet I haven't been able to get it work after all.

I've tried to move dependent declarations inside one file, using in their own namespace and as an inner namespace.

I've tried different combinations of ambient declarations with classic declarations.

I've tried changing modules into namespaces.

It only brought me to a point of desperation and dislike toward TypeScript. All I want is to make my Node.js library readily usable for TypeScript developers.

Most of the time I've running into issues where it says that my TypeScript is not a module. In other cases it couldn't find some types. Nothing but trouble. Please somebody help me with this.

**UPDATE**

Should I even include TypeScript with the library or should it be published on [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) instead?